# How to make MonoDevelop update it's cache after nuGet's restore?

Tags: monodevelop, nuget

When restoring packages via solution's context menu option "Restore NuGet Packages..." the MonoDevelop IDE still marks references to NuGet libraries as invalid and complains about non-existing namespaces. Restarting IDE helps as it clears MonoDevelop's cache, but is there a way to do this automatically? Perhaps some option in some settings that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. Whilst MonoDevelop will detect assemblies that have been removed, and indicates this in the Solution window by marking the reference in red, it does not detect assemblies that been added back.

Debugging MonoDevelop it seems as though MonoDevelop detects changes to the solution file and project file and will reload them. Other changes, such as assemblies being restored, are ignored.

If possible I will have a look at changing the NuGet addin so it asks MonoDevelop to check the references after a package restore.