# Error With Epplus.dll when compile (Excel integration)

Tags: excel, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a solution to integrate a tool allowing me to store data in the form of a table and export it in a format like excel to allow printing on paper. And to be able to modify the excel by hand to be able to import the data in unity.

I have to implement Epplus.dll which integrates a library allowing the access to the creation of excel spreadsheet and their backup. It works in editor but unfortunately when I try to compile my project I have an error (see attachment):

"Epplus is not allowed to be included"

Would you know how to make it included in the build, otherwise would you have a solution to my concerns if it does not include dependency on the final versions of unity?

Thank you in advance to all for the attention paid to my request

[See unity error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJYQP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't include it as asset.

Make reference to the library adding it from nuget: right click your project, Manage nuget packages, search Epplus and install it

You can follow basic instructions about nuget at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

Then, you can follow some getting started examples from [EPPlus in Github](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: added some links in my response

Comment: Thank you very much,
Previously I had epplus.dll which will allow me to call my excel library, after having included the nuget Epplus in VS, so I deleted my dll, and I do not know how to call my nuget in unity to use the epplus library through the nuget system.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I don't have much experience with unity, but you usually only need to add the `using OfficeOpenXml;` to get access to the library. Can you modify your question and show some code how are you using the library?

Comment: first as you said, I integrate the nuget epplus my project through visual studio

I have "Epplus by Jan Källman" in my nuget manager into visual studio.

And when i come back in my script on unity, and i have my "using OfficeOpenXml", it is red, because he not found the nuget i think.

Note : The using OfficeOpenXml work before, when i have dll brut into my unity project, but like i post before, unity dont work when the dll is include in asset folder

Comment: If shown in red that means that VS can't find the reference. Has you forced VS to download references: right click in solution root (in solution explorer) and clic Restore Nuget Packages. Also, expand the references folder in the solution explorer and check that none of them is marked with a yellow waring

Comment: When I restore the nuget, VS tells me "All packages are already installed and there is no element to restore." My nuget Epplus appears in my references in visual studio with the blue logo of the nuget. But it does not actually appear in unity (monodevelop) in references.

Do you think there is a manipulation to make unity with monodevelop receive nugets from visual studio?
Thank you for your time

Comment: I don't know monodevelop. Perhaps this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034543/777551 can help

Comment: Okay. Let's imagine that I do it sosu visual studio then. I added my nuget Epplus. And I open my script by writing "using OfficeOpenXml" to populate my nugget lib. Why does not it work? :/

Comment: ok i try to restart a new project from scratch.

Just i create unity project.
I create script
I open this script with VS
I add nuget "Epplus" to my project"
I load the nuget into my csproj with "Install-Package EPPlus -Version 4.5.2.1" 
I create "Using OfficeOpenXml" in my script.

At the end : VS no problem, Unity says "The type or namespace name "OfficeOpenXml" could not be found.